# String interpolation with cpp using strings passed as parameters outputs strange results

Tags: c++, arrays, string, char, printf

I want to print a report line consisting of a string passed into a function as a parameter, along with an integer.  It worked fine until I tried to use a string. My sanity check works, so this is <strike>pretty embarrassing</strike> part of learning.
Lesson: **compilation errors and google are your friends.**

```
void funct (int (*func)(int), int n, string label){
    res = (*func)(n);
    printf("Sanity?\n%s\n%s\n%d\n", "sanity check", "sanity check",42);
    printf("%s\n",label);
    printf("%s(%n) = %d", label, n, res); 

    return 
}
```

The hard part works (passing the function). The sanity check works. The last two prints don't work as I expected. Here is the output:

```
Sanity?
sanity check
sanity check
42
r
r(32000) = 648
```

In the debugger, `label` shows the value Im passing in - "*Lookups*" - but instead, it's printing a single character, and not even one that's part of the string. (Maybe let me know in the comments?)

Answer (score 0):

**SOLVED:**
It was trying to tell me the problem
`cannot convert 'std::__cxx11::string' {aka 'std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>'} to 'const char*'`

**TL'DR** 
`char*` not `string`...

```
// Unintended Output
string tester = "foo";
printf("%s <- not foo\n\n", tester);

// Intended Output
char* testerc = "foo";
printf("%s <- foo\n\n", testerc);
```

results in:

```
r <- not foo

foo <- foo
```

For function declarations:

`void func(char* stringParam){}` works, but
`void func(string stringParam){}` doesnt print what we want with this in the function
`printf("%s", stringParam);`

**Why?**

String interpolation with `printf` uses character arrays for `%s` not actual strings. (Not limited to `printf` either, is it? lmk)

So the solution was <strike>to convert the string using **c_str()** - `<string>.c_str()`</strike> specifying the correct object type for the function parameter. If you can't do that for some reason, maybe the casting would help you.

If anyone wants to time quick functions and report on their duration in `microseconds` (s, ms, μs, and ns all work in `chrono`'s `duration_cast`), this was the driving use case:

```
int timer (int (*func)(int), int n, char* label){
    auto t1 = std::chrono::steady_clock::now().time_since_epoch();
    (*func)(n);
    auto t2 = std::chrono::steady_clock::now().time_since_epoch();  
    auto dur = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::microseconds>(t2-t1).count();

    printf("Approach: %s: %d μs for %d iterations\n", label, dur, n); 

    return dur;
}
```

Now correctly outputs:

```
Approach: Lookups: 588 μs for 32000 iterations
Approach: IF-calcs: 962 μs for 32000 iterations
```

For the calls using arbitrary functions:

```
    int lookupTime = timer(lookupBuzz, iterations, "Lookups");
    int calcTime = timer(calcbuzz, iterations, "IF-calcs");
```

Readers: What's a better way to time things? What should be the fastest way to run fizzbuzz on the first *n* integers? Whats the best way to save the results? doing the latter with a basic array - `results[x]=fizzbuzz(x);` - seems limiting which is why Im only using 32000 for *n*, but I want to use 10M as the benchmark.)